# Call a function from a class in a different file - React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm basically trying to call a function (getValue) from a class (Time) in a different file, but there is some issues.

Here is the code for the two files:

Time.js

```
export default class Time extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
        input: '',
        input2: '', 
        checked: false
    }
    this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);
}

hrChange = e => {
    this.setState({input: e.target.value}, function () {this.getValue()})
}

minChange = e => {
    this.setState({input2: e.target.value}, function () {this.getValue()})
}

amPm = () => {
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked}, function () {this.getValue()}) 
}

getValue = () => {
    const list = [
        this.state.input, 
        this.state.input2, 
        this.state.checked  
    ]
    return (list)
}

render() {
    return(
        <text>some stuff</text>
    )
}
}
```

NewStorage.js

```
function NewStorage() {
const time = () => {
    var obj = new Time();
    var list = obj.getValue()
    const 
        hrInput = list[0], 
        minInput = list[1], 
        pm = list[2]

    return(
        console.log(hrInput, minInput, pm, list)
    )

return(
    time()
)
}

export default NewLocalStorage;
```

The main issue isn't that I can't call the function, it is that when I call the function, the values of input, input2, and checked are all the original value ('', '', false), not the updated versions (ex: '11', '30', true).

I'm not sure on how to solve this issue.

Comment: React's pervasive  use of `return (...)` is a cancer. You do **not** need to wrap every return value in `(...)`. `return list;` or `return console.log(...)` or `return time()`  or `return <text>...</text>` is sufficient. Sorry that doesn't answer your question, I'm trying to help with other things that might be confusing you.

Comment: Using a callback, `this.setState(..., function () {this.getValue()})` does not make sense. The [setState callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is called after the state transition takes place, and `getValue` does not do anything meaningful in this context.

Comment: You write a `NewStorage` function but `export` a `NewLocalStorage` identifier. One of these seems like a typo. Additionally you write `const time = () => ...` and then `return time()` there's zero reason to define `time` as a nullary function and then call it immediately. It's the same effect as writing the contents of the `time` function directly in your `NewStorage` function.

Comment: Your question is tagged `react-hooks` but they are nowhere to be seen in the code in question. React hooks would dramatically improve this code if you... use them.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!! They are really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inclusion of the `react-hooks` tag suggest your hunch that hooks are applicable to solving your problem. I would agree -

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

function Time ({ hour, minute, onChange }) {
  const [h,setHour] = useState(hour)
  const [m,setMinute] = useState(minute)
  useEffect(_ => onChange({ hour: h, minute: m }), [h, m])
  return <div>
    <input value={h} onChange={event => setHour(event.target.value)} />
    <input value={m} onChange={event => setMinute(event.target.value)} />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Time onChange={console.log} />, document.querySelector("main"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

In a more sophisticated example, we can use the `Time` component's `onChange` callback to update nested state in a parent component, `MyForm` -

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useCallback } = React

function Time ({ hour = 0, minute = 0, onChange }) {
  const [h,setHour] = useState(hour)
  const [m,setMinute] = useState(minute)
  useEffect(_ => onChange({ hour: h, minute: m }), [h, m, onChange])
  return <div>
    <input value={h} onChange={event => setHour(event.target.value)} />
    <input value={m} onChange={event => setMinute(event.target.value)} />
  </div>
}

function MyForm () {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ time: { hour: 5, minute: 30 }, foo: "bar" })
  const onTimeChange = useCallback(t => setData({ ...data, time: t }), [])
  return <form>
    <Time hour={data.time.hour} minute={data.time.minute} onChange={onTimeChange} />
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
  </form>
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.querySelector("main"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create a class and call the function in another file, why not use React functional components and hooks?

Try something like this:

```
const Clock = () => {
   const [hour, setHour] = useState();
   const [min, setMin] = useState();
   const [am, setAm] = useState(true);

   useEffect(() => {
      // Get your clock to work in here...
   }, [hour, min, am]);

   return (
      <div>
         {//This will post your clock here, and if you need the values, you 
            can set/use them individually as needed.}
         {hour}:{min} {am ? 'am' : 'pm'}
         {//The ternary statement will modify this portion for you in code.}
      </div>
   );
}
```

If you want to use the values globally, you may want to try using the React hook useContext(). This will allow you to access those specific values anywhere you want, but requires a bit more setup.

Context, if you don't know will turn your react app into Redux, without using Redux. Below is an example of what you need to do.

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const QuizContext = createContext();
```

then you add the context to your App.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MainMenu from './Components/MainMenu';
import Quiz from './Components/Quiz';
import EndScreen from './Components/EndScreen';
import { QuizContext } from './Helpers/Context';

function App() {
  const [gameState, setGameState] = useState('Menu');
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Quiz App</h1>
      <QuizContext.Provider value={{gameState, setGameState, score, setScore}}>
        {gameState === 'Menu' && <MainMenu/>}
        {gameState === 'Quiz' && <Quiz/>}
        {gameState === 'EndScreen' && <EndScreen/>}
      </QuizContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then you can access the context from individual components as long as they are children of App.

Example:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { QuizContext } from '../Helpers/Context';
import {Questions} from '../Helpers/QuestionBank'

const Quiz = () => {
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0)
    const [optionChosen, setOptionChosen] = useState('');
    const {setGameState, score, setScore} = useContext(QuizContext);

    const nextQuestion = () => {
        Questions[currentQuestion].answer === optionChosen ? setScore(score + 1) : console.log(score);
        setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1); 
        
    }

    const finishQuiz = () => {
        Questions[currentQuestion].answer === optionChosen ? setScore(score + 1) : console.log(score);
        setGameState('EndScreen');
    }

    return (
        <div className="Quiz">
            <h1>{Questions[currentQuestion].prompt}</h1>
            <div className="options">
                <button onClick={() => setOptionChosen('optionA')}>{Questions[currentQuestion].optionA}</button>
                <button onClick={() => setOptionChosen('optionB')}>{Questions[currentQuestion].optionB}</button>
                <button onClick={() => setOptionChosen('optionC')}>{Questions[currentQuestion].optionC}</button>
                <button onClick={() => setOptionChosen('optionD')}>{Questions[currentQuestion].optionD}</button>
            </div>
            {currentQuestion === Questions.length -1 ? <button onClick={finishQuiz}>Finish Quiz</button> : <button onClick={nextQuestion}>Next Question</button>}
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Quiz
```

I learned this method from a Tutorial from PedroTech on YouTube. I followed along to create this. I wanted to make sure I didn't take credit for his work.

Comment: It would be beneficial for you to show how these examples can be applied directly to the user's code, especially so if the examples were executable